# How to set 100% width for a parallax image?

Tags: css, html, image, size, parallax

I have a parallax class which contains the image as well. I tried to make the image responsive by setting the image width to 100%, but its just not working.

```
.parallax1 {
  /* The image used */
  background-image: url('Images/FloralPurple.png');
  /* Full height and width */
  height: 100%; 
  width:100%;
  /* Create the parallax scrolling effect */
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

and the following is the HTML code:-

```
<div style="height:230px;background-color:#001332;font-size:20px; color: #ffffff; padding: 18px">
Some text which defines the image</div>
```

I tried adding the image tag inside of my div, but still, nothing got changed.

Thank you

Comment: 100% of what? The window? Its parent div?

Comment: Please add the relevant HTML.

Comment: Here, I am talking about the image

Comment: Even after mentioning the width to be 100%, when I resize the window, the image looks bigger and goes out of the window

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The size of your background image is defined by the `background-size` css property.
When set to `cover` the image will scale in order to fill the div. You can set the background size to the following values:

- `cover` As described the div gets covered. The image gets scaled and cropped.
- `contain` The image is always full completely visible and gets scaled in order to be completely visible.
- `100px 50px` A fixed size. The image gets streched.
- `50% 100%` A percentage. The image gets stretched.

Example:

```
background-size: 100%;
```

The image would always fill the div. But get stretched in order to do so.